# How to pass this script to an html format with javascript or vbscript?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I have the following code.

```
Option Explicit
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim ws,fso,RootFolder,MyFile,firstNameInput,fileStream
Do
    firstNameInput = inputbox("Digite o nome que deseja adicionar")
Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
RootFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop")
MyFile = RootFolder & "\bots.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile,ForAppending,True)
fileStream.WriteLine firstNameInput
fileStream.Close
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

What I want is to be able to edit the bots.txt file through a web page. It can also be done in javascript.
I think in something like this:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>  
<Html>  
   <Head>  
      <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">  
         Sub Sample()  
          Dim iRow  
          Set objNotepad = CreateObject ("notepad.Application")  
          Set objWork = objNotepad.Work.Open ("C:\Users\Erick\Desktop\bots.txt")     
          iRow = 1  
          With objNotepad  
              Do while(iRow, 1).value <> ""  
                  (iRow, 1).activate  
                  iRow = iRow + 1  
              Loop  
                 (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("fname") (0).Value   
                 MsgBox "Data Added Successfully”, vbinformation  
                 Document.GetElementsByName ("fname") (0).Value=""  
             End With  
             ObjWork.Save  
             ObjWork.Close  
             Set objWork = Nothing  
         End Sub  
      </script>  
      <style type="text/css">  
         fieldset {  
            border: #00cc00 2px solid;  
            padding: 10px;  
            color: green;  
      </style>  
   <body  
<form>  
   <fieldset>  
      <legend>Welcome</legend>  
      <center>  
         <!--<img src="" alt="Mountain View"><br> -->
         Bot Name:<br>   
         <input type="text" name="fname" Value=""><br>  
         <input type="button" onclick="Sample()" value="Submit"/><br>  
      </center>  
   </fieldset>  
<form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

> **Note**: I want to modify the file without changing the names that already exist, putting one name below the other when adding.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Does something about the code not work? Are you getting errors?

Comment: The code don't run I don't undestand because I'm not a programmer, I just copied on web, the example 1 run, but the 2 don't work.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a "fix this code I found someplace else for me" type of page. You are expected to have at least a general understanding of the language you're using. You're also expected to have made an honest attempt to solve the problem yourself (describe what you have tried and how that actual results were different from what you expected). If you can't do that SO is not the right place for you.